# In which property on GA could I see extra Facebook Ads UTM parameters?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, utm, facebook-ads

so on my Facebook ads, i have set the following parameters: source, medium, name and content and I added an extra one: Ad Set Name. I was able to find the first 4 in Traffic acquisition on Google Analytics 4, but where could I find the last one? or any custom parameters for that matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to send it with UTM parameters.

Here's an example:

```
utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=paidsocial&utm_campaign={{campaign.name}}&utm_content={{ad.name}}_{{ad.id}}&utm_term={{adset.name}}
```

Then you can find it in Google Analytics.